# SVN: someone committed code under my name, how to find out who changed the "Author"

Tags: svn

Someone checked in code to SVN, but it somehow says my name in the "Author" section. Nobody has my login credentials, so how can I find out who originally committed it or who put it under my name? There is nothing in the logs since the last normal commit, other than the commit (not by me) listed under my name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn:author` property is unversioned and by default it's not possible for a regular user to modify it. However, if your Subversion configuration allows modifying the unversioned properties, it could be that someone adjusted the property using Subversion client. I'd suggest analyzing the events in your [Operational (high-level) log](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/operational-logging/) if you have one.

You should look for these events.

- Event that shows your commit. It should tell who was the authenticated author at the time of commit:

  > ```
  > commit r1234 
  > Repository: MyRepo 
  > User: <USERNAME> 
  > Host: <IP ADDRESS>
  > ```
- Event that shows a revision property of revision r1234 has been modified by a user using Subversion client. The event specifies the originating
  IP and the name of the user who changed the value of the `svn:author`
  revision.

  > ```
  > change-rev-prop r1234 svn:author
  > Repository: MyRepo
  > User: <USERNAME>
  > Host: <IP ADDRESS>
  > ```